# How to find next graphic in notebook?

Tags: graphics, notebooks, cells

I have a notebook bloated by graphics and would like to delete many of them. To do this I would like an expression to find the next graphic. I tried:

```
NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], "Graphics", Next, CellStyle]
```

But that did not work.

Comment: Sigh. I fiddled with this and don't have a good answer. However, there are a couple things that might satisfy you. First, if you Option-Click the cell bracket (blue thing on the right edge), all cells of the same type will be selected. I do this to clean things up. I Option-Click an output cell and then tap the Delete key. So, not graphics specific, but maybe it'll be good enough.

Comment: Second, if you know something about the input that created the outputs you want to delete, you might be able to do something like this: NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Plot", Next, 
 WrapAround -> True]; SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]. Yeah, that's going require you to do one at a time.

Comment: Third, you can mark input cells as not evaluatable (Cell menu->Cell Properties). So, if you're in the habit of selecting everything and evaluating, this will suppress output of cells that you're not currently interested in.

Comment: Fourth (this can be a bit scary), you can expose the internals of cells by selecting a cell and doing a Command-Shift-E (or whatever the equivalent is on your machine). Same command toggles it back. So, go to a "bad" cell, expose its textual representation, and find something that you could do a text search on (like maybe "GraphicsBox"). Now, select everything in your notebook and do the command so they're all exposed. Now in a new Input cell do something like NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "GraphicsBox", All]. Delete them all. Now select all and toggle back to normal display.

Answer (score 5):

### How to find next graphic

In principle, `SelectionMove[nb, Next, Graphics]` does this, but it works only if the selection is already inside of a `Cell`. And unfortunately, it doesn't return `$Failed` when there is no graphics, and `SelectionMove` can't move the selection (this is a bug, reported as [CASE:4909617]).

It could be used as follows:

```
(* Create a notebook *)
nb = CreateWindow[
   DocumentNotebook[
    CellGroup[{TextCell["Graphics Group", "Section"], 
      ExpressionCell[RandomImage[1, {200, 200}], "Output"], 
      ExpressionCell[Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -3, 3}], "Output"]}, Closed]]];

(* Select graphics in the second cell *)
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, 2];
SelectionMove[nb, Before, CellContents];
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Graphics];
```

We can check whether something is selected with `NotebookRead[nb]` or with `` "CursorPosition" /. Developer`CellInformation[nb] ``. But this whole approach is highly inefficient, has an undesirable side-effect (opening cell group even if the group doesn't contain graphics), and also feels not completely reliable due to buggy `SelectionMove`.

---

### Efficient way to find and select next graphic without processing the whole Notebook

We can implement `selectNextGraphics` as follows:

```
cellContainsGraphicsQ[cellObj_CellObject] := 
  Head[FirstPosition[NotebookRead@cellObj, _GraphicsBox]] =!= Missing;
findNextCellWithGraphics[None] = None;
findNextCellWithGraphics[cellObj_CellObject] := Module[{cobj = cellObj},
   While[Head[cobj] === CellObject && ! cellContainsGraphicsQ[cobj], 
    cobj = NextCell[cobj]]; cobj];
selectNextGraphicsInCell[None] = None;
selectNextGraphicsInCell[cellObj_CellObject] := 
  Module[{cp = "CursorPosition" /. Developer`CellInformation[cellObj]},
   If[MatchQ[cp,
     "CellBracket" | None], SelectionMove[cellObj, Before, CellContents]];
   SelectionMove[ParentNotebook[cellObj], Next, Graphics];
   If[MatchQ[
     "CursorPosition" /. Developer`CellInformation[cellObj], {{0, 0}} | cp], $Failed]];
selectNextGraphics[nb_NotebookObject] := 
  Module[{ns = NotebookSelection[nb], cells, cellObj},
   cells = Cells[ns];
   Switch[cells,
    {}, If[Head[cellObj = findNextCellWithGraphics[NextCell[ns]]] === CellObject, 
     selectNextGraphicsInCell[cellObj], None],
    {_}, If[selectNextGraphicsInCell[First[cells]] === $Failed, 
     selectNextGraphicsInCell[findNextCellWithGraphics[NextCell@First[cells]]]],
    {__}, selectNextGraphicsInCell[findNextCellWithGraphics[First[cells]]]]];
```

---

### Efficient way to find and select next `Cell` containing graphic with preprocessing the whole Notebook

I can suggest tagging all `"Output"` cells containing `GraphicsBox[...]` with tag `"ContainsGraphicsBox"`, and then use `NotebookFind` to select them one-by-one:

```
(* Create a notebook *)

nb = CreateWindow[
   DocumentNotebook[{CellGroup[{TextCell["Text Group", "Section"], 
       TextCell["Mary had a little lamb.", "Text"], 
       TextCell["Its fleece was white as snow.", "Text"]}], 
     CellGroup[{TextCell["Graphics Group", "Section"], 
       ExpressionCell[ Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -3, 3}], "Output"], 
       ExpressionCell[ Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}], "Output"], 
       ExpressionCell[ Plot[x^3, {x, -3, 3}], "Output"]}]}]];

(* Tag all "Output" cells containing GraphicsBox[] as "ContainsGraphicsBox" *)    

Scan[If[Head[FirstPosition[NotebookRead@#, _GraphicsBox]] =!= Missing, 
   CurrentValue[#, CellTags] = {"ContainsGraphicsBox"}] &, 
 Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Output"]]

(* Find the next cell tagged "ContainsGraphicsBox" *)

NotebookFind[nb, "ContainsGraphicsBox", Next, CellTags];
```

One can use `SetSelectedNotebook[nb]; NotebookLocate["ContainsGraphicsBox"]` to select them all at once.

---

### Better approach to selectively delete cells with graphics

Another approach is to add to every `"Output"` cell containing `GraphicsBox` a `CellDingbat` with buttons allowing to delete the cell or discard the buttons:

```
(* Create a notebook *)

nb = CreateWindow[
   DocumentNotebook[{CellGroup[{TextCell["Text Group", "Section"], 
       TextCell["Mary had a little lamb.", "Text"], 
       TextCell["Its fleece was white as snow.", "Text"]}], 
     CellGroup[{TextCell["Graphics Group", "Section"], 
       ExpressionCell[ Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -3, 3}], "Output"], 
       ExpressionCell[ Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}], "Output"], 
       ExpressionCell[ Plot[x^3, {x, -3, 3}], "Output"]}]}]];

(* Add to every "Output" cell containing GraphicsBox a CellDingbat with buttons 
allowing to delete the cell or discard the buttons*)

Scan[If[Head[FirstPosition[NotebookRead@#, _GraphicsBox]] =!= Missing, 
   CurrentValue[#, CellDingbat] = 
    Cell[BoxData[
      ToBoxes@Column[{Button[Text["Delete Cell", Background -> Red], 
          NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]], Appearance -> None], 
         Button[Text["Discard this", Background -> Green], 
          SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell]; 
          CurrentValue[SelectedCells[], CellDingbat] = Inherited, Appearance -> None]}, 
        Left, 0]]]] &, Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Output"]]
```

Here is a video demonstrating how it works:

[image: screenvideo]

We also can combine both approaches, and add functionality to go to the next cell with graphics after pressing the delete or discard button for the current cell:

```
(* Create a notebook *)

nb = CreateWindow[
   DocumentNotebook[{CellGroup[{TextCell["Text Group", "Section"], 
       TextCell["Mary had a little lamb.", "Text"], 
       TextCell["Its fleece was white as snow.", "Text"]}], 
     CellGroup[{TextCell["Graphics Group", "Section"], TextCell["Plot 1", "Text"], 
       ExpressionCell[Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -3, 3}], "Output"], TextCell["Plot 2", "Text"], 
       ExpressionCell[Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}], "Output"], TextCell["Plot 3", "Text"], 
       ExpressionCell[Plot[x^3, {x, -3, 3}], "Output"]}]}]];

(* Add to every "Output" cell containing GraphicsBox a CellDingbat with 
buttons allowing to delete the cell or discard the buttons *)

Scan[If[Head[FirstPosition[NotebookRead@#, _GraphicsBox]] =!= Missing, 
   CurrentValue[#, CellTags] = {"ContainsGraphicsBox"}; 
   CurrentValue[#, CellDingbat] = 
    Cell[BoxData[
      ToBoxes@Column[{Button[Text["Delete Cell\n& go next", Background -> Red], 
          SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell]; 
          SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Cell]; 
          With[{sc = SelectedCells[]}, SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, Cell]; 
           NotebookDelete[sc]; 
           NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "ContainsGraphicsBox", Next, CellTags];], 
          Appearance -> None], 
         Button[Text["Discard this\n& go next", Background -> Green], 
          SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell];
          CurrentValue[SelectedCells[], CellDingbat] = Inherited; 
          SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell]; 
          NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "ContainsGraphicsBox", Next, CellTags];, 
          Appearance -> None]}, Left, 0]]]] &, Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Output"]]
```

This plays well with *Mathematica*'s Undo/Redo functionality.